# How to add domains to rails app in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, dns

I deployed my app to heroku and I added my godaddy domain to heroku with:

```
heroku domains:add www.domain.com
heroku domains:add domain.com
```

But when I type `domain.com` sometimes it doesnt work and it redirects me to godaddy. Only  `www.domain.com` works fine. Is there anything I am missing in configuration?
This is my DNS records setting

Host

```
   @    68.178.232.100 

   @    75.101.145.87 
   @    75.101.163.44 

   @    174.129.212.2
```

C-NAME(Alias)

```
     www          proxy.heroku.com
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From what you've described your Heroku setup is fine. You need to make sure your GoDaddy DNS records are correctly pointing to Heroku, and specifically that your @ record is set correctly so the root domain is handled by Heroku.

**Update:**

The Heroku IPs are:

```
75.101.163.44
75.101.145.87
174.129.212.2
```

`68.178.232.100` is GoDaddy. Delete that record and you should be ok.

Comment: I have updated the question with  DNS settings records above.

Comment: It looks like your setup is fine. As Wizard of Ogz points out, it may just take some time to fully propogate, and while in propogation it is possible that (depending on which nameserver your request is routed through) some requests will succeed and others will fail to reach the server.

Comment: I deployed the app over couple of months ago though.

Comment: Thank you andrew,i deleted the go daddy ip.

Answer (score 2):

Check your DNS settings.  If your DNS is set up properly you may just need to wait for it to propagate out to other nameservers, which can take up to a week.  In all likelihood it will only take a day or two.